# Xcode Linker error: _OBJC_CLASS_$_CIImage 

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode

When building my Xcode project I am receiving a Linker error that I cannot figure out how to resolve.  If I build the following code the compile step completes just fine but I get an error from the Linker saying '"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CIImage", referenced from Objc-class-ref-to-CIImage in AppController.o' followed by a second error that looks identical except CIImage is replaced with CIFilter followed by a statement that says "Symbol(s) not found"

```
CIFilter *transform = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAffineTransform"];
[transform setValue:inputBitmap forKey:@"inputImage"];
NSAffineTransform *affineTransform = [NSAffineTransform transform];
[affineTransform rotateByDegrees:3];
[transform setValue:affineTransform forKey:@"inputTransform"];
CIImage * result = [transform valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
```

This code is in my AppController.m, and the Linker error showed up after I put the following statement up at the top:

```
#import "QuartzCore/CIFilter.h"
```

I put that import statement in because, without it I get a Compiler error on the first line of code that says "No +filterWithName method found" and I read somewhere that Cocoa automatically includes CIImage.h but not CIFilter.h.  So ... with the #import the compiler error disappears but I get the linker error.  :(

Any ideas what is causing the Linker error and how to get rid of it?

FYI:  I tried searching for duplicate files as described in another "xcode linker error" thread herein, but could not find any duplicate files in my project.  I also went to the trouble to create a completely new Project, and copy all my code from the old project to the new one, just to eliminate the possibility that I had somehow accidentally corrupted my project files.  I still have the same issue in my new project.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure you've added the QuartzCore framework to your project (Linked Frameworks)!

Comment: That was indeed the issue.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 20):

Add "CoreImage" framework.

(Well, I know this question is old. But I had a same problem and adding "QuartzCore" framwork didn't help it).

Comment: After all the excepted answers saying QuartzCore this answer is a breath of fresh air - lifesaver!

Comment: all these years passed and it's still lifesaver!